# How do I show the transition probabilities in a graph of a Markov process?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, version-9, labeling, markov-chains

How do I get `Graph` to display the transition probabilities for a Markov process as labels on the graph's edges? The information is clearly present in the graph, but only displays when I hover over the edges. Is there a way to get the information to display as edge labels (without [going through complex machinations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41497/37))?

For example,

```
mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, ({
     {0.6, 0.1, 0.3},
     {0.2, 0.7, 0.1},
     {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}
    })];
Graph[mp]
```

gives

[image]

with no labeling of edges, even though I can hover over any edge to see the associated transition probability (as a tooltip).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can extract the probabilities from the properties of the edges and assign them as edge labels using

```
g = Graph[mp];
Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeLabels] = PropertyValue[{g, #}, "Probability"]) &,
      EdgeList[g]]

g
```

[image]

You can find this (and other) properties using the [`PropertyList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PropertyList.html)  function:

```
PropertyList[{g, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}]

(* {"Probability", EdgeLabels, EdgeShapeFunction, EdgeStyle} *)
```

From here, I used [`PropertyValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PropertyValue.html) to set the properties. I imagine there are a few other (and possibly better/simpler) ways to accomplish this.

Comment: great answer - appreciate the conciseness and the extra tidbit at the end on PropertyList.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `MarkovProcessProperties[mp, "TransitionMatrix"]` as edge labels directly in `Graph`:

```
mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, {{.6, .1, .3}, {.2, .7, .1}, {.3, .3, .4}}];

Graph[mp, 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> 
    MarkovProcessProperties[mp, "TransitionMatrix"][[## & @@ e]]}]
```

[image]