# How to label edges of Continuous Markov Process

Tags: markov-process

I can label a `DiscreteMarkovProcess`

```
P = {{0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 0, 2/3,
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 1/4, 0, 3/4, 0}, {1/4, 0, 0, 0, 3/4, 0}};
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P];
 Graph[proc, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]
```

but how to label a `ContinuousMarkovProcess` (without using its discrete version)
For example

```
P = {{-7, 2, 5, 0}, {0, -5, 0, 5}, {0, 0, -2, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
pr = ContinuousMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0}, P];
g = Graph[pr, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]
```

does not work. Inspired by the discrete answer [How do I show the transition probabilities in a graph of a Markov process?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47432/how-do-i-show-the-transition-probabilities-in-a-graph-of-a-markov-process?rq=1) I tried

```
PropertyList[{g, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}]
Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeLabels] = 
    PropertyValue[{g, #}, "TransitionRate"]) &, EdgeList[g]]
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `Automatic` `EdgeStyle` settings over-ride the user-specified `EdgeStyle` settings when the first argument of `Graph` is a `ContinuousMarkovProcess`.

```
gcmp = Graph @ pr;

AnnotationValue[gcmp, EdgeLabels]
```

> ```
>  {3 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> Placed[2, Tooltip], 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> Placed[5, Tooltip], 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed[5, Tooltip], 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed[2, Tooltip]}
> ```

**1.** A work-around: We can re-set `AnnotationValue[gcmp, EdgeLabels]` and replace `Tooltip` with `Center:

```
AnnotationValue[gcmp, EdgeLabels] = 
  AnnotationValue[gcmp, EdgeLabels] /. Tooltip -> Center;

gcmp
```

[image]

**2.** Another simple work-around: add the option `GraphStyle -> {}`:

```
Graph[pr, GraphStyle -> {},  
 EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]
```

[image]

```
Graph[pr, GraphStyle -> {}, 
  EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> 
     MarkovProcessProperties[pr, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]}]
```

[image]